# Would we call someone who is biased towards people of their own country "racist"?

Tags: meaning

Is someone who favours someone from their own country - regardless of the other persons colour - still classed as racist?

Comment: Only if they wrongfully discriminate (not merely favor) based on *race* (not necessarily related to color). If your question is about *ethnicity* (as opposed to to nationality or citizenship) then I would say yes, that might fall under racism.

Comment: *Nationalistic* or *insular* might be better terms. The term *racist* is definitely overused, for example when used to described discrimination based on religion.

Comment: Thank you, Michael. I have just joined this site, so I'm a little unfamiliar with it, at the moment. How do I sign out, please?

Comment: It's well hidden!  You'll see it if you click on "StackExchange," top left of your screen.

Answer (score 4):

I'd call such a person a [***chauvinist***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/chauvinist).

> A person displaying aggressive or exaggerated patriotism.

Reference:
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/chauvinist